# HTTP basic request in Android

Tags: android, http, authentication, post, request

I want to do a POST HTTP request to the serving to receive some cookies from the server. During this POST request I also need to send some data like login and password. I found a lot of solutions but nothing is working, everything that I found is deprecated.

So the question is: how can I make a HTTP POST request to receive form the server some cookies after?

Comment: Check out this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)